# C# WPF. Фактический размер окна не соответствует заданному

Tags: c#, wpf

Итак, есть свежесозданная WPF форма, все что есть в форме это один элемент Border.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="149" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172">
            <Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

В режиме разработки это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вставил это изображение в paint - действительно 200x200, как и указано в свойствах.

В режиме исполнения это выглядит так:

[image: Режим исполнения]

Размер окна уменьшается. Чего я делаю не так? Пробовал ставить SizeToContent="Manual" - результат такой же.

Comment: А какая фактическая цель стоит? Если вам нужен `Border` конкретных размеров, то задавайте размеры ему, ибо рамка/заголовок окна ОСзависимые

Comment: Цель - написание приложения с фиксированным размером. И я не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы размеры в режиме исполнения и разработки соответствовали. В приведенном примере же у рамки заданы размеры - они соответствуют в обоих случаях, но из-за того что окно меньше, пропадает отступ снизу и справа.

Comment: а) Делайте окно без заголовка и бордюра (`WindowStyle="None"`), рисуйте их самостоятельно. б) Забейте на фактические размеры окна и устанавливайте размеры контенту (`SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`)

Comment: Благодарю, с установкой размера окна по контенту и одним элементом, фактически задающий размер - все получается. Не ожидал столкнуться с подобными проблемами после WinForms.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующим образом:
Вставьте Border в DockPanel

```
<DockPanel>
    <Border Margin="10">
        <Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

У меня этот вариант работает.